# C# Dynamically add DataGridViewRow malfunction

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a program that will add rows dynamically in certain conditions, I've tried implement the function in this way:

```
if (student.UUID == AppliedStudent)
{
    using (DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow())
    {
        row.SetValues(new object[] { lesson.Name, Course.Course_Name, lesson.Level, lesson.Time, Teacher.C_Name, lesson.Price, Classroom.Classroom_Name });
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

With this code, it can add in rows indeed however they are all empty, all those rows has no data in it. (It has been confirmed that `lesson`, `course` and `Teacher` aren't `null`.) Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by myself at last, I replaced the `row.SetValues` to `row.CreateCells`:

```
if (student.UUID == AppliedStudent)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.CreateCells(dataGridView1, lesson.Name, Course.Course_Name, lesson.Level, lesson.Time, Teacher.C_Name, lesson.Price, Classroom.Classroom_Name);
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

With this code it will work well. Thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to leave out the `using`part. After it the `row`object will be disposed:

```
if (student.UUID == AppliedStudent)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.SetValues(new object[] { lesson.Name, Course.Course_Name, lesson.Level, lesson.Time, Teacher.C_Name, lesson.Price, Classroom.Classroom_Name });
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the answer, yet it didn't solve the problem :/